# Zonal Statistics Python Code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zonal-statistics, error-000735

I'm trying to calculate the number of certain raster cells within the individual buffers identified by the FID and I'm not sure what else I need to change in this code to make it run:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
import numpy as np

# overwrite existing datasets
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Define workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

in_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features, "lyr")

FIDS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]

InputRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(InputRaster, "rdlayer")

for item in FIDS:
    fieldName = "FID"
    FID_item = str(item)
    EXP = '"FID" = ' + str(item)
    print EXP
    arcpy.AddMessage("Selecting from nest buffers where " + EXP)

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("shp", "NEW_SELECTION", EXP)
    result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr").getOutput(0))
    print result
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(result) + " nest buffers selected")

    OutputTable = "suit_" + str(item)
    ZonalStatisticsAsTable("shp","FID","rdlayer",OutputTable,"DATA","SUM")
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/csetash/PycharmProjects/Covariates/SuitHab.py", line 22, in <module>
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features, "lyr")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6043, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Features: Value is required
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In your script tool interface, what data type have you chosen for the in_features parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Input in Select Layer by Attribute must be a feature layer or a table view. The input cannot be a feature class or table. [Make Feature Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm)

Your input is "shp" which may be a feature class.